# When is a function $f$ a functional?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I have a general question about functionals, about linear functionals. How can I prove that a function is a linear functional? What should I follow when I try to prove this? I didn't really understand how is this working and I really want to learn. Can you try explain me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Would you have a specific example that you can share? [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearFunctional.html) defines this quite well.

Comment: So if I have f($y_{n}$) = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{2}-1}{n^{2}+1}y_{n}$ it is enough to calculate $f(\lambda x_{n} + \mu y_{n})$ to prove that f is a linear functional?

Comment: And f($\lambda x_{n} + \mu y_{n}$) should be equal with $\lambda f(x_{n}) + \mu f(y_{n})$, right?

Comment: @Mariana That's right.